# Hacking ASME conference template for SB3C conference

Tags: document-classes

The SB3C abstract format follows the ASME conference format rather closely, but the SB3C does not have a LaTeX template. I am trying to modify the ASME LaTeX class to meet the specifications of the SB3C, and I am down to one final aesthetic change. The SB3C conference header should look like:

[image]

After some modifications to the order and font in the original ASME template, I can only produce:

[image]

where the `3` is not quite a superscript despite having used `\textsuperscript{3}`. The portion of the ASME class that produces this header is:

```
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null\vspace*{-26pt}             % Took out ASMElogo provision
   \vbox{\hbox to \textwidth{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{\hskip3pc}}
   \hbox to 46pt{\vbox to 46pt{\vss\hsize46pt\vss}}\end{tabular}\hss
  \vbox{\hsize37pc\scriptsize\sf\vskip\baselineskip%
  \bannerfnt\begin{flushright}% added flushright to properly wrap long conference names
  \hfill \@confshortname\par
  \hfill \@conffullname\par
  \hfill \@confmonth\ \@confdate, \@confcity, \@confcountry

  \vskip.5in
  \hfill {\pnumfnt\@papernum}\end{flushright}}
  \hskip1pc}}
  \vskip.15in%.25in original value w/out flushright
  \vskip .25pc{\large\twlsfb
               \begin{center}\leftskip.5in plus1fill\rightskip\leftskip
               \@title\par\end{center}}
  \vskip2pc{\begin{center}\@author\par\end{center}}\vskip12pt}
\fi
```

However, I don't understand how to modify it so that the `3` displays as a proper superscript. Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you sure you are supposed to do this kind of *magic*?

Comment: When the alternative is using a Word template, absolutely!

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out my solution.  The problem is in the lines:

```
\vbox{\hsize37pc\scriptsize\sf\vskip\baselineskip%
\bannerfnt\begin{flushright}%
```

\bannerfnt is the size of the font used for the header, but it is bigger than \scriptsize.  So, it seems that the three rows of the tabular environment are being made shorter than the font for the text within those rows.  Changing this to:

```
\vbox{\hsize37pc\bannerfnt\sf\vskip\baselineskip%
\bannerfnt\begin{flushright}%
```

seems to solve the exponents and also the spacing between the lines.

Comment: Yes, I found the same bug last year. Your approach is basically what I did.